# Update Jira filter permission - jira python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using jira python to access Jira resource.

I created a filter using the `create_filter` method, it sets the permission to **Private** by default.
I want the filter to be accessible by others and I don't find an option to specify the permission.

Is there a way that I can update the permission in jira python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/filter-createFilter says that this call "Currently sets permissions just using the users default sharing permissions" so jira-python may not have a call to help you.
POST /rest/api/2/filter/{id}/permission may work after the filter has been created